# Not possible downgrade to Flutter 1.22.6

Tags: flutter

I am trying to downgrade my Flutter version to 1.22.6

I am using Flutter channel stable.

This is the output when I put in the terminal the command

flutter downgrade 1.22.6

```
There is no previously recorded version for channel "stable"
```

Yesterday was the last time I could downgrade to Flutter 1.22.6

Are there any changes in Flutter lastly?

Version 1.22.6 is listed in https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases?tab=macos

Should I download the SDK by hand?

Comment: you can manually download that version of Flutter and point your "flutter" command into that one. Just out of curiosity... why will you downgrade SO much? Libraries will not work as expected with all the null safety changes and latest changes/improvements of Dart

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla, I know, but I have a couple of old FLutter projects that need this version

Comment: I ended up manually downloading and created a new command "flutter2" and "flutter" for each version until I could migrate my old projects. Another option is to call it "flutterold" if your quick response memory for "flutter" expects to run the latest version. You will also need to use that specific version to clean, compile, build, etc

Comment: @MarianoZorrilla, sounds good, I will try your solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no more possible to downgrade from flutter 2.xx to 1.xx. However you can use flutter Version Manager fvm its specifically made to control flutter versions plus along with that you can install flutter sidekick as well.Use multiple versions of flutter specific for your projects I am attaching link for you.
[FVM](https://fvm.app/) [Flutter Sidekick](https://github.com/leoafarias/sidekick)